# SQL Sorting Inquiry

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a sql table with a column named `reference_number`.

`reference_number` has values with a format of **x-MMYY-xxxx**.
(**MM** is for month while **YY** is for year. **-xxxx** are auto-increment.)

My issue is that if I enter the following values into `reference_number`

**Mar 2012 (x-0312-xxxx)**

**Apr 2012 (x-0412-xxxx)**

**Jan 2013 (x-0113-xxxx)**

`ORDER BY reference_number` would sort them as

**x-0113-xxxx**

**x-0312-xxxx**

**x-0412-xxxx**

Is there a way to sort `reference_number` by the correct order of date.

Comment: what is hidden inside those `x` characters?

Comment: It is ordering them correctly. Smallest to greatest. MySQL doesn't know you intended 0312 to be monthYear. Another suggestion would be to keep the date in another column (in addition to in your order reference, not instead of), or yearDay might work (if my brain is working correctly).

Comment: You may have to order by the year part and the month part as two separate pieces of data.

Comment: @JonStirling you are correct. sql sorts it the regular way, ignoring the format of **x-MMYY-xxxx**. i need a way to teach sql thatit should sort by the correct date order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that your `reference_number` column's data type is a character field?

Sorting by a character field will "do its best" to understand and interpret the data into a format by which it want sort, in this instance you'll note that it's interpreted the date part of your reference as a numerical value and as such, will sort them this way.

Alphanumeric data will be sorted as such.

If you require the data sorted by date, there are a number of solutions you can employ but ultimately you will need a `DateTime` value to sort by.

Either add a `reference_date` column and add the date values to this, either by direct insert or a DB trigger etc.

IMHO, you must have date values to be able to sort by date, however you decide to achieve that.